# Let image size be relative to sibling flex element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### How can the height of the image be relative to the height of the elements on the left?

I'm trying to create the following layout:

[image: Flexbox with image height relative to text]

**What I tried**

I'm trying to achieve this with flexbox. My html looks like this. I have `display:flex` on the container `<div class="split">`. That container houses two children containers: `<div class="intro__primary">` and `<div class="intro__secondary">`. The first has an `h1`, `p` and `a`. The second the `img`.

I gave both children a width of 48%, and I want my image to occupy as much vertical space as possible, but not more than the height of `<div class="intro__primary">`.

HTML

```
<section class="intro">
  <div class="split">
     <div class="intro__primary">
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
        <a class="btn"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="intro__secondary">
        <img>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.split {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.intro__primary {
        width: 48%;
        align-self: flex-start;
}

.intro__secondary {
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.intro__secondary > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The code above results in an image that has a way larger height than the container with the text on the left. I played a lot with all the properties but can't fix it. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Frankly this is something you should be using a **background** image for and this solves the whole problem. Your image is *styling* not content and so does not need to be in the HTML at all.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.split {
  max-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.intro__secondary {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.intro__secondary img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* you can also use object-fit: contain; */
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <div class="split">
     <div class="intro__primary">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <a class="btn"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="intro__secondary">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="random-image">
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried tihs, but it doesn't seem to be working in this situation.

Comment: @Osocman Try removing the width property on the image. Or set ```width: auto```

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately the result is still an `intro__secondary` and `img` that have too large a height.

The image and `intro__secondary` utilize all available width, and while keeping aspect ratio, the height becomes too large.

What I try to create is that the image utilizes maximum width and height, as long as the height is no larger than `intro__primary`.

Comment: I've made edits above. Please check them out. I initially said min-height when I meant max-height....my bad.

Comment: Thanks for your response again! I tried your suggestions, but they didn't work sadly! Now, I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the height property of `intro__secondary`, as It doesn't take the full height of the `split` container. This is probably because I've never explicitly stated the height of the `split` container. Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Yeah I've added it in the second line of the snippet above.

```.split { max-height: 100px; }```

If it still dosen't work, add ```height: auto``` to all your divs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  `max-height : 100px` and `height : auto` didn't fix the problem in my situation. I found a solution though! Giving `position : relative` to `split` and `position : absolute` , `float : right` and `right : 0` to `intro__secondary` made it work.